PCIe BAR access
I have a FPGA card plugged in to a host memory over PCIe. I want my host to access 2GB of DDR memory on card. Does that mean I'll have to request for a BAR size of 2GB ?
My understanding is that, if I request for a 32KB of address space and if host assigns it as 0x0f03_0000, then, it can access upto 0x0f03_7FFF. So read/write request issued by host in this range would end up on my card.


Does that mean I'll have to request for a BAR size of 2GB ?

In most systems you can't request so much memory for a BAR.
With the i.MX6 PCIe for example the maximum memory assigned to BAR PCIe is 15MB.
To access a large amount of memory you will need to add memory controller in FPGA to split memory space.

My understanding is that, if I request for a 32KB of address space and
if host assigns it as 0x0f03_0000, then, it can access upto
0x0f03_7FFF. So read/write request issued by host in this range would
end up on my card.

Yes, exactly.
